# Restoring a site (SEO) after 6 months of downtime

Tags: seo, ranking, downtime

I have a site that used to average 200 - 490 unique visitors per day (with about 80% of this coming from organic SEO) in December 2011.

I turned it back on in the last week or so, and, (as you would expect) the SEO and number of unique visitors has reduced by approximately 90%. The search phrases that the site used to rank for - it does no longer. Infact, it's barely even ranking for it's own name since relaunching the site.

So far I have:

1. Setup a `sitemap.xml` and `Google Webmaster Tools` and submitted the sitemap to Google for indexing.
2. Eliminated a few of the errors found by `Google Webmaster Tools` (some of the URLs have changed slightly, so I wrote some `mod_rewrite` rules to fix this.)
3. Ensured that the site is now on a fast, reliable and stable server.

The domain name has stayed the same and the site has retained 80% - 90% of the content that it previously had.

What can be done (if anything) to 'restore' the SEO that the site used to have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

James, sorry to say but i don't think it will automatically gain previous position by just uploading same content and fixing Google webmaster suggestion. As your website was down for such a long time and it lost all its credential/rankings/ and other reputation. As search engine does not love 404 pages !!

Apart from this, there are many updates rolled out by Google which focuses on quality of content and natural backlinks. I strongly recommend improving content and generating natural backlinks for your website to get those rankings back.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

If you have same content as again, i think there should not be any problem gaining SEO of last time, but what all you need is little time.

Beside this i would like to say some point that may help a bit more

- In Google webmaster tool, check out daily how much incoming links are
  there and how it is increasing or decreasing daily.
- Check how much page is submitted, and indexed in Sitemap section.
- Update the content a little bit and add some new content so that
  Google should get attention again and crowl whole site as soon as
  possible.
- check of your keywords are fresh for today's visitor and search
  quarry? if not then update those keywords, specially for Title, h1 h2
  and images.

Beside Google check if Bing and Yahoo have indexed your pages or not.
also there may be chances that in this long gap, many site that were pointing to your domain, due to unavailability, link may be removed, so you need to build the link again upto some extent via forum and updating those links again.

I guess these all should work.