# Website not indexed after domain expired and the site was down for a week

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index, coverage

My website was well indexed and everything was working but unfortunately some weeks ago someone forgot to renew the domain and the website was down for more than a week.

We renewed the domain and everything came back as it was except that the website isn't indexed anymore.
I waited two weeks but nothing changed, on Google Search Console everything seems to be okay and I even tried to send a new sitemap in the hopes that it would help.
Someone knows what else I can do?

Comment: Related: [Effect on Google rankings if my site is down?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/effect-on-google-rankings-if-my-site-is-down)

Comment: Related: [Restoring a site (SEO) after 6 months of downtime](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49400/restoring-a-site-seo-after-6-months-of-downtime) and [Bringing a site back online (with about 3000 internal pages) after two years?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49130/bringing-a-site-back-online-with-about-3000-internal-pages-after-two-years)

Answer (score 1):

If you have links to your website then Google will "rediscover" it once these are recrawled.

If you don't have links then its a good idea to build quality ones anyway as these are votes for you website, and the more high quality ones you have the more prominent your site will be in the Search Results (Search Engine Results Placement - SERPs)

Comment: This information is only partially correct.  Links can help, but they need to be relevant to the site - its very much quality over quantity - indeed poor quality / to many unrelated links will likely get you de-indexed.  Google have long moved on from the Pagerank days you seem to be describing and its now about their E-E-A-T paradigm.